# Any way to inspect Orbeon form instances in the browser?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Is there any way to inspect the XForms instances on a specific page, from the browser, using Orbeon?  Something a little bit like "inspect element" in modern browsers, for dev purposes.

I found [this page](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/xforms-inspector), but it does not explain how to enable it on a page (or globally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is most likely to enable it globally, by adding the following to your `properties-local.xml`:

```
<property as="xs:boolean"
          name="oxf.epilogue.xforms.inspector"
          value="true"/>
```

And note that if you're using Form Builder, you'll then want to disable it, as the XForms Inspector [currently isn't supported with Form Builder](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1254).

Comment: @FlorentGeorges Then it's a bit more annoying. You can still disable it before loading Form Builder, and enable it again before loading your form. (Which is what I do, when I need the XForms Inspector.) Maybe we should just add some CSS to hide the XForms Inspector in Form Builder.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges So this is just what I did. It will be in 4.10. And for now, if it's bothering you too much, you can add that piece of CSS to your `form-builder.css` locally. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/abb67576f01a6570fca00419445f7c3395014e6e

Comment: @FlorentGeorges And thank you for bringing this up. Bringing our attention to annoyances like this one helps us improve the product.